# cant get PHP $_ [SESSION] working in another PHP page

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm using axios to query the backend, basically I have a page called action_user.php which creates an instance of db_user.php by making `$emp= new user();` and then goes to call its related function for example `getLogin()`, within getLogin I make `$_SESSION["info"]=$user.`
once authenticated I go do some operations on the catalogue from another file.php called `action_catalogue.php` which makes a new instance of `db_catalogue` by making `$emp= new catalogue();` calling the function `getCatalogue();`.
in summary the problem is i cannot get the SESSION value in `another.php` file
example of what the files look like:

**frontend login:**

```js
axios.post('http://localhost/test/action_user.php', { 
          action:"getLogin",
          username: this.username,
          password:this.password}).then(response).....if(success) {window.location.href =            "http://localhost:3000/catalogue";
}
```

**action_login.php**

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}
include('db_login.php');
$emp = new login();
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'getLogin') {
    $emp->getLogin();
}
```

**db_login.php**

```php
require(db_connect.php);
class login extends dbSetup{
    getLogin(){
     somecheck...
     $_SESSION["user"]=$user;
     echo $_SESSION["user"]; <==== correctly print username 
    }
}
```

**frontend catalogue:**
`axios....http://localhost/test/action_catalogue.php..`

**action:catalogue:**

```php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}
include('db_catalogue.php');
$emp = new catalogue();
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'getCatalogue') {
    $emp->getCatalogue();
}
```

**db_catalogue.php**

```php
require(db_connect.php);
class catalogue extends dbSetup{

 getCatalogue(){
    $user=$_SESSION["user"]
    var_dump ("$user") <<==== Error  array(0) {}
 }

}
```

I have noticed in the tmp folder of xammp a session file is created that contains the information saved on the session with the name sess_(for example A), then when I am redirected to the Catalogue page and getCatalogue is done, another file is created that is called sess_(for example B)

**UPDATE: i maked two file that called by two button**

frontend:

```
    handleSet = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost/test/test.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      };
      handleGet = () => {
    
        fetch('http://localhost/test/test1.php')
        .then(response => response.json(),)
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      }
```

php: test.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["info"]="USER123";
    $str="set";
    echo json_encode($_SESSION);

}
?>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

when i call handleSet i can correctly get the json from php:
{info: 'USER123'}
but when i call handleGet i only  get [],but i noticed when i go Network a go seraching test1.php there are {info: 'USER123'} correctly printed i cant figureout what it causing this issue

Comment: It looks like you know how to use `session_start` properly, so why do you call it in the `getCatalogue` method?

Comment: ops , its a copy error mb

Comment: Probably `var_dump ("user")` is also a copy error? It should be `var_dump ($user)` to get your result. Otherwise it would just return the string `user`.

Comment: Yes it is a copy error